# Why does AWS Dynamo SDK do not provide means to store objects larger than 64kb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I had a use case where I wanted to store objects larger than 64kb in Dynamo DB. It looks like this is relatively easy to accomplish if you implement a kind of "paging" functionality, where you partition the objects into smaller chunks and store them as multiple values for the key.

This got me thinking however. Why did Amazon not implement this in their SDK? Is it somehow a bad idea to store objects bigger than 64kb? If so, what is the "correct" infrastructure to use?

Comment: This is just my initial thought, but dynamoDB is a database, not cloud storage. If you need to store something large like that, you could always use S3.

Comment: If you need to store anything larger, store a reference to s3. Your SimpleDB/DynamoDB should store whatever you are going to search/index your record with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, it's an understandable trade-off DynamoDB made.  To be highly available and redundant, they need to replicate data.  To get super-low latency, they allowed inconsistent reads.  I'm not sure of their internal implementation, but I would guess that the higher this 64KB cap is, the longer your inconsistent reads might be out of date with the actual current state of the item.  And in a super low-latency system, milliseconds may matter.

This pushes the problem of an inconsistent Query returning chunk 1 and 2 (but not 3, yet) to the client-side.

As per question comments, if you want to store larger data, I recommend storing in S3 and referring to the S3 location from an attribute on an item in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, the maximum item size in DynamoDB is now 400K, rather than 64K as it was when the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

From a Design perspective, I think a lot of cases where you can model your problem with >64KB chunks could also be translated to models where you can split those chunks to <64KB chunks. And it is most often a better design choice to do so.

E.g. if you store a complex object, you could probably split it into a number of collections each of which encode one of the various facets of the object.

This way you probably get better, more predictable performance for large datasets as querying for an object of any size will involve a defined number of API calls with a low, predictable upper bound on latency.

Very often Service Operations people struggle to get this predictability out of the system so as to guarantee a given latency at 90/95/99%-tile of the traffic. AWS just chose to build this constraint into the API, as they probably already do for their own website ans internal developments.

Also, of course from an (AWS) implementation and tuning perspective, it is quite comfy to assume a 64KB cap as it allows for predictable memory paging in/out, upper bounds on network roundtrips etc.